# How to pass these parameters to method - Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

I have a strange requirement.

I have a method (posting only relevant code, not full code.)

```
def updateLevelFile(level, __data,  mode='r+', encoding='utf-8'):
                    # I want this to be dynamic
                    __data[index]["tasks"][0]['choices'][0]["4"] = str(host['httporhttps'])
                    # I want this to be dynamic
```

Need `# I want this to be dynamic` section to be dynamic.

means I will pass this method which keys to update and the values too ..

Keys can be different each time, for some instances we can have key `["tasks"][2]["task_default_text"]`

How to do it?

Whole code in this method is being used so many times, I don't want to replicate it, I want to make it a method and call again and again.

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED?**

I have tried to pass

`'"tasks": [{"choices": [{"4": "1"}]}]'` equivalent JSON of `["tasks"][0]['choices'][0]["4"]` and decoded into dictionary

and then do something like `__data[index]to_update` but its obviously invalid syntax.

Comment: What about defining a new method `to_update` that will unpack JSON the way you want it and then just call `to_update(__data[index])`?

Comment: Local watchdog only work with an `while True :`.  `While True : if data is changed : #update_everything`. But your method is wrong , need set everythings on a data excepted ! `Call_Local_FUNC ---> Call_Golbal_VAR ----> PUSH_TO_GLOBAL_FUNC -----> SET_GLOBAL_VAR` , take a gun for hit your computer !

Comment: One golden OOP rule says "Keep Complexity Low Level".  Pass strings (key, value) to a method, not complete lists, arrays, keys etc. Or use iterators ...

Answer (score 2):

Try this (assuming I understand your question correctly):

```
def set_value_for_path(obj, path, value):
    for key in path[:-1]:
        obj = obj[key]
    # Note: will raise an exception if path is an empty list
    obj[path[-1]] = value
```

and in your function

```
set_value_for_path(
    __data[index],
    ("tasks", 0, 'choices', 0, "4"),
    str(host['httporhttps'])
)
```

Now you can turn second argument of `set_value_for_path` function into `updateLevelFile` function param, e.g.

```
def updateLevelFile(level, __data,  mode='r+', encoding='utf-8', path):
    # ...
    set_value_for_path(__data[index], path, str(host['httporhttps']))
    # ...

updateLevelFile(level, __data, 'r+', 'utf-8', ("tasks", 0, 'choices', 0, "4"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [kwargs](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/), a example below to give an idea.

```
def updateLevelFile(level, __data,  mode='r+', encoding='utf-8', **kwargs):
    task_index = kwargs.pop('task_index')
    key = kwargs.pop('key')
    key_index = kwargs.pop('key_index')
    __data[index]["tasks"][task_index][key][key_index]["4"] = str(host['httporhttps'])

#Example function call
updateLevelFile(level, __data, task_index=2, key="task_default_text", key_index=2)
```